# How to view images when path is saved to database and image is saved to folder in Django?

Tags: django

I'm new in Django. I need help. I want to display images. Here I saved image path to database and images to folder. Please help me to display those images.

**views.py**:

```py
def uploadfile(request):
   print('inside upload logic')
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = FileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
        # ImageUpload(request.FILES['File_Name'])  
         myfile = request.FILES['File_Name']

         fs = FileSystemStorage()
         filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
         uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
         newdoc = FileUpload(File_Name=myfile.name, File_path=uploaded_file_url,  Description=request.POST['Description'])
         newdoc.save()
         #return HttpResponse("File uploaded successfuly")  
         return render(request, 'Login/fileupload.html')   
   else:
      form = FileUploadForm()
      return render(request, 'Login/fileupload.html', {
      'form': form
   }) 

def dataretrive(request):
   newdoc=FileUpload.objects.all()
   return render(request,'Login/displayimage.html',{'FileUpload':FileUpload})
```

MY Model:

```py
 class FileUpload(models.Model):
    File_Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    File_path = models.FileField(upload_to='')
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Upload_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: can you post your model here?

Comment: class FileUpload(models.Model):
    File_Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    File_path = models.FileField(upload_to='')
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Upload_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Comment: please update your question and add this model there

Comment: and where do you want to display these images Django templates?

Comment: just access the `url` property of that `FileField` like `File_path.Url`, whether you're sending it in `JSON` or using it in templates directly

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/usage/#how-do-i-use-image-and-file-fields

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField)

Add this to your model:

```py
 class FileUpload(models.Model):
    File_Name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    File_path = models.FileField(upload_to='')
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    Upload_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    return "%s/%s" % (instance.id, filename)
```

In you settings.py file make sure to set MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

To access the MEDIA_URL in template you must add django.template.context_processors.media to your context_processeors inside the TEMPLATES config.

Add this to your template:

```html
{% if instance.image %}
  <img src="{{ instance.image.url }}" class='img-responsive' />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `File_path` is already a `FileField` why would he need an image field, `FileField` works fine for images as well

Comment: @Aarif you are right, of course it's not wrong but it's not consider best practice.